# M1 Mac can't launch any apps in simulator

Tags: xcode, macos

When trying to launch any app in Xcode 12.3 on any of the available simulator devices, I get the following error. It's a new M1 MacBook Air running the latest macOS Big Sur.

```
ARM64 maximum VM address is '0x7ffffe000000', which is too low. Please add 'arm64_maxoffset=0xFC0000000' to your boot-args and reboot the device.
ThreadSanitizer: unsupported vm address limit 0x7ffffe000000, expected 0x800000000000.
```

It doesn't seem right to that I have to have to add any launch arguments. Google returns nothing.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that having the thread sanitizer on caused this error. Disabling it solved it.

Edit:

You can disable the thread sanitizer under [YOUR TARGET] > Edit Scheme > Run and then uncheck the checkbox under the Info tab